# Squid3 TCP_MISS/200

Tags: squid

I have squid3-3.4.8 on Debian installed. Some gif's are with HIT in  /var/log/squid3/access.log, but many of then are MISS. Here are logs:

```
1465154641.561    243 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/54.235.160.51 image/gif
1465154686.677    355 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/75.101.135.237 image/gif
1465154690.942    196 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/75.101.135.237 image/gif
1465154761.749    430 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/54.243.156.79 image/gif
1465154826.042    416 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/54.83.16.157 image/gif
1465154896.843    362 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/23.21.149.132 image/gif
1465155059.310    183 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 488 GET http://track.adform.net/serving/unload/? - HIER_DIRECT/37.157.6.252 image/gif
1465155081.000    361 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/54.225.223.150 image/gif
1465155133.835    128 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 488 GET http://track.adform.net/serving/unload/? - HIER_DIRECT/37.157.6.252 image/gif
1465155151.674    349 10.10.70.71 TCP_MISS/200 356 GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping? - HIER_DIRECT/23.21.95.141 image/gif
```

and here are `/var/log/squid3/cache.log`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 05 Jun 2016 19:32:13 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa PSAa PSDa OUR LEG NAV INT"
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.4.8)
Connection: keep-alive


----------
2016/06/05 22:32:13.835 kid1| http.cc(1062) persistentConnStatus: local=10.10.84.115:48806 remote=37.157.6.252:80 FD 16 flags=1 eof=0
2016/06/05 22:32:13.835 kid1| http.cc(1062) persistentConnStatus: local=10.10.84.115:48806 remote=37.157.6.252:80 FD 16 flags=1 eof=0
2016/06/05 22:32:31.325 kid1| client_side.cc(2407) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client local=10.10.84.115:3128 remote=10.10.70.71:57168 FD 13 flags=1
2016/06/05 22:32:31.325 kid1| client_side.cc(2408) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client REQUEST:
---------
GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping?h=15min.lt&p=%2F&u=DqS6y2zqfeBcFYFs&d=15min.lt&g=54232&g0=default&n=0&f=00001&c=9&x=0&m=0&y=31461&o=1249&w=916&j=270&R=0&W=0&I=1&E=0&e=0&r=&b=19769&t=BsrbM3BDP0jmCOnR3pCdgvMIDaWsQK&V=78&tz=-180&sn=6&EE=0&_ HTTP/1.1
Host: ping.chartbeat.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.15min.lt/
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache


----------
2016/06/05 22:32:31.481 kid1| http.cc(2260) httpStart: httpStart: "GET http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping?h=15min.lt&p=%2F&u=DqS6y2zqfeBcFYFs&d=15min.lt&g=54232&g0=default&n=0&f=00001&c=9&x=0&m=0&y=31461&o=1249&w=916&j=270&R=0&W=0&I=1&E=0&e=0&r=&b=19769&t=BsrbM3BDP0jmCOnR3pCdgvMIDaWsQK&V=78&tz=-180&sn=6&EE=0&_"
2016/06/05 22:32:31.481 kid1| http.cc(2216) sendRequest: HTTP Server local=10.10.84.115:53318 remote=23.21.95.141:80 FD 15 flags=1
2016/06/05 22:32:31.481 kid1| http.cc(2217) sendRequest: HTTP Server REQUEST:
---------
GET /ping?h=15min.lt&p=%2F&u=DqS6y2zqfeBcFYFs&d=15min.lt&g=54232&g0=default&n=0&f=00001&c=9&x=0&m=0&y=31461&o=1249&w=916&j=270&R=0&W=0&I=1&E=0&e=0&r=&b=19769&t=BsrbM3BDP0jmCOnR3pCdgvMIDaWsQK&V=78&tz=-180&sn=6&EE=0&_ HTTP/1.1
Host: ping.chartbeat.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.15min.lt/
Pragma: no-cache
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.4.8)
X-Forwarded-For: 10.10.70.71
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive


----------
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: 'http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping?h=15min.lt&p=%2F&u=DqS6y2zqfeBcFYFs&d=15min.lt&g=54232&g0=default&n=0&f=00001&c=9&x=0&m=0&y=31461&o=1249&w=916&j=270&R=0&W=0&I=1&E=0&e=0&r=&b=19769&t=BsrbM3BDP0jmCOnR3pCdgvMIDaWsQK&V=78&tz=-180&sn=6&EE=0&_'
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| http.cc(705) processReplyHeader: processReplyHeader: key '9A7E3C59EFE4B10B4AE720A6F2E141DA'
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| http.cc(746) processReplyHeader: HTTP Server local=10.10.84.115:53318 remote=23.21.95.141:80 FD 15 flags=1
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| http.cc(747) processReplyHeader: HTTP Server REPLY:
---------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: image/gif
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 43
Connection: keep-alive

GIF89a
----------
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| ctx: enter level  0: 'http://ping.chartbeat.net/ping?h=15min.lt&p=%2F&u=DqS6y2zqfeBcFYFs&d=15min.lt&g=54232&g0=default&n=0&f=00001&c=9&x=0&m=0&y=31461&o=1249&w=916&j=270&R=0&W=0&I=1&E=0&e=0&r=&b=19769&t=BsrbM3BDP0jmCOnR3pCdgvMIDaWsQK&V=78&tz=-180&sn=6&EE=0&_'
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| http.cc(916) haveParsedReplyHeaders: HTTP CODE: 200
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| ctx: exit level  0
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| WARNING: Could not determine this machines public hostname. Please configure one or set 'visible_hostname'.
2016/06/05 22:32:31.595 kid1| WARNING: Could not determine this machines public hostname. Please configure one or set 'visible_hostname'.
2016/06/05 22:32:31.674 kid1| client_side.cc(1459) sendStartOfMessage: HTTP Client local=10.10.84.115:3128 remote=10.10.70.71:57168 FD 13 flags=1
2016/06/05 22:32:31.674 kid1| client_side.cc(1460) sendStartOfMessage: HTTP Client REPLY:
---------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Jun 2016 19:32:31 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: image/gif
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 43
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Via: 1.1 localhost (squid/3.4.8)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any help is appreciated.
EDITED: Pragma: no-cache says my squid not to cache. Is there a way to overcome this? Because with that logic servers can say to not cache everything.

Answer (score 2):

> Because with that logic servers can say to not cache everything.

Yes, that's the point.  Origins and user agents know a lot more about the cacheability of resources, and the desirability of servicing a request from the cache, so they get a set of knobs to twiddle to control caching.  You don't want to override that in your cache, because it breaks all sorts of important assumptions that everyone else relies on.